# Programatically access Apple's crash logs of my app on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, crash

I have an iOS app where I log my app states changes in a .log file and there is an provision within the app to extract the debug logs and email to the dev team for debugging.

I would also to be able to programmatically copy App crash logs (crash dump) generated by Apple (in case my app had crash in the past) and send it along with the app generated logs.

I know that the crash dump is placed at location ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/Device-Name.

Not sure if I can programmatically access this location path using published API's (without fearing Apple rejection during review).

I only found Apple documentation which talks of accessing the logs using either XCode or via the Diagnostics utility option in iPhone settings.